# EC2 Spark can not connect to Ganglia

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, ganglia

I am trying to investigate all the possible methods how to monitor Spark. Ganglia seems to me as very interesting option, but unfortunately I have problem to set it up.

Particularly I am using Spark and it's build in command ./spark-ec2 with option --ganglia after the cluster set up, it prints out that ganglia is started at http://:5080/ganglia, but unfortunately when I try to connect it I am getting that website is not available. I have also checked in EC2 console, that port 5080 is available from anywhere.

So my question is if anyone has some idea, how to possibly connect to Ganglia and what can possibly be wrong? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings? I had the same problem until I realized my firewall was blocking the 5080 port. A priori, the connection to Ganglia should be as easy as it seems.

Comment: it seems that quite a few modules are missing from `/etc/httpd/modules/`.

Answer (score 0):

This is applicable to Spark 1.3.0: 
I had this problem, and the issue is that apache did not start because it is trying to start php 5.5 but machine has php 5.6

Edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
and change 
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp-5.5.so
to 
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp-5.6.so
(last LoadModule command in config file)

Then restart apache with: 
service httpd start

This worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that quite a few modules are missing from `/etc/httpd/modules/`.
I've commented some lines out of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` - lines no `154, 196, 197, 198`, I've prepended `#` in the beginning, as such:

```
#LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
```

additionally I've created sym-link to libphp

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so /etc/httpd/modules/libphp-5.6.so
```

lastly I've started `httpd` service

```
service httpd start
```

that did the trick!